# How do you select a plotted image in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to convert a plotted image with filled in areas to grayscale to use in another area, can't seem to find anything on how to do this.
This is my code to create the plotted image:

```
image = skimage.io.imread("anaconda2/Videos/(4F) 2008-05-22 10.30.59 HOOSH/2008-05-22 10.30.59 HOOSH0010.png")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(image)
plt.ylim(ymin=720, ymax=0)
plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=1280)
plt.plot(x2,y,'r-',x3,y,'r-',x4,y,'r-',x5,y,'r-',x6,y,'r-',x7,y,'r-',x8,y,'r-',x9,y,'r-',x10,y,'r-',x11,y,'r-',)
plt.fill_betweenx(y,x2,x3,color='yellow')
```

Basically, I just need to be able to make this plotted image a variable to use later for other functions.
Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by the "plotted image"? Do you want a bitmap of just the plot area, with a colour value for each pixel? Or do you want the whole figure object (i.e. including the axes, labels, titles, etc.)?

Comment: The image itself in the plot area, not the axes or labels or anything else

Comment: Would that not just be the `image` variable you already have?